# Stopping AVPlayer on iOS

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer to play a live stream from the Internet. AVPlayer can be paused, but on resume it starts off from the moment it was paused, just like a TiVO. AVPlayer does not have a stop method.

How does one make it continue with what is currently being broadcast (as though you turned your car radio off and back on)?

Comment: does it depend on the streaming server?

Answer (score 1):

`-(void)seekToTime:(CMTime)time`

use this method to get to beginning of file

Answer (score 1):

To stop an `AVPlayer`:

```
[player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
```

That will free up all the memory and processor resources it and its associated asset consumed. Simple as that.

Answer (score -1):

SeekToTime wont stop the audio, so once you reach the end if you only call seekToTime it will just start playing again like a loop. You can use the below version with a callback to pause the video/audio as soon as the seek is completed so it resets and stops simultaneously.

```
[_player seekToTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1) completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {
    [_player pause];
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 [player pause];
[item_ removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:nil];
[item_ removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" context:nil];
[item_ removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" context:nil];
[item_ removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" context:nil];
 player=nil;
```